# Why in the ε-δ definition of a limit is x∈D instead of just ℝ

Tags: real-analysis, limits, epsilon-delta

ε-δ definition:

$(\forall \epsilon >0) \ (\exists \delta >0)(\forall x \in D) (0 < \lvert x - a \rvert < \delta \Rightarrow \lvert f(x) - L \rvert < \epsilon)$

I don't understand why in the epsilon-delta limit definition x is defined as being x∈D instead of just using x∈ $\mathbb{R}$. Would specific issues arise for certain functions or types of functions if I were to use x∈ $\mathbb{R}$ instead?

Comment: What is $x$? The limit, or the argument of the function whose limit we're considering?

Comment: The $\epsilon-\delta$ definition of what?

Answer (score 5):

I think that $D$ is the domain of the function.  Take for example the function $f(x)=\ln(x)$.

You know that this function is a map between $\underbrace{(0,\infty)}_D\to\mathbb R$, so in this case it does not make sense to study continuity at a point $x = -2$ ,for example, as this function is not defined here. If you have a function $f: \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$, for example $f(x)=x$, then your $D = \mathbb R$ and then you can let $x \in \mathbb R$.

Comment: @Tiffany Re Eduardo Magalhães' answer, the formal definition of continuity of a function **insists** that only those elements that are in the *domain* of the function are to be considered.  There are sophisticated reasons for this, but for someone new to the subject, it is reasonable to consider the reasons as **irrelevant.**  That is, mathematicians **arbitrarily** decided that the notion of continuity of a function should be so defined.  Later, as you confront more complicated continuity problems, you will see the *elegance* behind this definition.

Answer (score -2):

I would like suggest as answer conception of limit with respect to some set D in metrical spaces, for example Rudin W. - Principles of mathematical analysis,1976, 83-84p. :

4.1 Definition. Let $X$ and $Y$ be metric spaces; suppose $D \subset X$, $f$ maps $D$ into $У$, and $p$ is a limit point of $D$. We write $f(x) \to q$ as $x \to p$, or
$$\lim\limits_{x \to p}f(x)=q$$
if there is a point $q\in Y$ with the following property: For every $\varepsilon >0$ there exists a $\delta > 0$ such that
$d_Y(f(x),q)<\varepsilon$ for all points $\forall x \in D$ for which $0<d_X(x,p)<\delta$. The symbols $d_X$ and $d_Y$ refer to the distances in $X$ and $Y$, respectively.

If $X$ and/or $Y$ replaced by the real line, the complex plane, or euclidean space, the distances are replaced by absolute values or by norms.

**Addition.**(Tuesday, July 18 2023, for anonymous  downvoter, who possibly have arguments for showed critic)

Formally limit for function $\lim\limits_{x\to c}f(x)=L$ with respect to $E$ is following (Vladimir A. Zorich - Mathematical Analysis I-Springer (2016), page 106 or [Limit_of_a_function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_of_a_function)) :

$$(\forall \varepsilon>0)(\exists \delta>0)(\color{red}\forall x \in E)\Big(0<|x-c|<\delta\Rightarrow |f(x)-A|<\varepsilon \Big)$$

Also we can write it as following

$$(\forall \varepsilon>0)(\exists \delta>0)\Big(\color{red}\forall x \in E\cap \{x:0<|x-c|<\delta\}\Big)\Big( |f(x)-A|<\varepsilon \Big)$$

By choosing a different $E$ we can control the extent to which the second universal quantifier (indicated in red) is applied.

Let's consider the well-known [Dirichlet function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_function)

$$D(x)=\begin{cases} 1,  & x\in \mathbb{Q} \\
0, & x\notin \mathbb{Q}
\end{cases}$$

If we take $E= \mathbb{R}$, then limit doesn't exists, but it exists if $E= \mathbb{Q}$ or $E= \mathbb{R}\setminus\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: Explicit critic is welcome.